# Printing with two for loops

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out X and Y coordinates from two separate arrays using two for loops. Each point is either decremented or incremented. The grid space is 500x500. I should basically end up with the output displaying a line of asterisks going either up or down. The arrays are populated correctly, and the X and Y coords are decremented or incremented correctly. I can't get it to work....

The populate board method fills the b1 array with the point's x member and the b2 array with the point's y member.

```
populateBoard(b1,b2,point);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if(i == b2[i] && j == b1[j])
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

What is my logic error in the above code? Yet when I use this it works (only for one point obviously).

```
if(i == b2[0] && j == b1[0])
```

Comment: What does the third argument of your populateBoard method do?

Comment: What is input (method arguments) and expected output?

Comment: Should you be using 1 loop instead of two?

Comment: The populate board method fills the b1 array with the point's x member and the b2 array with the point's y member.

Comment: Can you give us the value of b1 and b2. Also, your expected output.

Comment: Put all important info in question (use [edit] option to do that). Don't make people search for information in comments. Also provide example of arrays content and explain what results you want to get from them.

Comment: Could you show us some example? It doesn't need to be for `500x500`, `5x5` would be enough (and most likely preferred).

Comment: Are you sure you don't want something like `if(b2[i] > 0 && b1[j] > 0)` as your test?  As it is, you won't see anything interesting unless `populateBoard` happens to put both b1 and b2 = {0, 1, 2,, 3, ..., 499}.

Comment: I know it does not need to be 500 by 500. I want to simulate random terrain generation in 2D, with the line from the OP being the ground. All Y members are inc and dec randomly. I would rather have a big representation than a little one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your above code is the assumption that in the i/j-th iteration of your double loop you'll be encountering a point whose x/y value happens to be exactly equal to i/j.

The working solution is as follows

```
private static void populateBoard(int[] xs, int[] ys, int w, int h)
{
    Set<Point> points = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<xs.length;i++)
    {
        int x = xs[i];
        int y = ys[i];
        points.add(new Point(x,y));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<h;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<w;j++)
        {
            Point p = new Point(j,i);
            if(points.contains(p))
                System.out.print("■");
            else
                System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

When I run this code against a trivial example:

```
int[] xs = {1,4,1,4,1,2,3,4};
int[] ys = {1,1,3,3,4,4,4,4};

populateBoard(xs, ys, 6, 6);
```

it produces the following (correct) output:

```
......
.■..■.
......
.■..■.
.■■■■.
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
boolean[][] temp = new boolean[matrix.length][matrix.length];
for (int i = 0; i < b1.length; ++i)
    temp[b2[i]][b1[i]] = true;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
        System.out.print(temp[i][j] ? "*" : " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```